# Add custom parameter with .draw()

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables with server-side processing. Now I want to send an extra parameter with the request so I can do some grouping of data. For the initial call, I can do this by adding `data` to the `ajax`.

```
var dt = $('#products').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "{{ route('product.data') }}",
    "data": function(d){
      d.grouping = 1;
    }
  },
```

This adds a parameter `grouping` with the value of `1`.

Now I have created multiple filters for the data, on a button click I'm redrawing the table to get the filtered products.

```
$("[data-search]").click(function () {
  // Setting dt.columns(x).search('')
  dt.draw();
});
```

How will I be able to modify the `grouping` value just before calling `dt.draw()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve values from your filters in the function for `data` option.

For example:

```js
var dt = $('#products').DataTable({
  // ... 
  "ajax": {
    "url": "{{ route('product.data') }}",
    "data": function(d){
       d.grouping = $('#filter').val();
    }
  },
  // ... 
});
```

Comment: I should add this inside the `.draw()` function?

Comment: @Timo002, use it in `ajax.data` as you did before, updated my answer.

Comment: Aaah, now I'm getting it! Thought I needed to reset that value on every draw() and that the "data" in the `ajax.data` only was used for the first init!